# Python regex equivalent for perl

Tags: python, perl

what is the equivalent of following Perl condition in Python

```
if($line=~/DramBase/)
```

I tried the following but it didn't match(the line at the bottom)

```
if(re.match( r'DramBase', line)):
```

I had to change it to

```
if(re.match( r'.*DramBase', line)):
```

to match this line

```
# -DF0.CCM0.DramBaseAddress1 0x00004001
```

Is there a flag to match it anywhere on the line without explicitly matching starting characters ?

Comment: I think you'd use `re.search`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.search), not [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.match).  `re.match` only matches as the beginning of the string, while `re.search` matches anywhere, like in Perl.

Comment: Thanks. How is this supporting Python philosophy that "Only one obvious way to do it".  Can `re.match` be replaced with `re.search(r'^...')` ?

Answer (score 2):

See [re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) for an explanation

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the **beginning of string** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match **at the beginning** of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> If you want to locate a match **anywhere in string, use search() instead** (see also search() vs. match()).